# Calling a function to set variables in Init

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm trying to create a profile, like Facebook, and have a contact variable and contactInfo variable being passed in that have the userID and a list of phone numbers, emails, and addressess respectively.
In order to display the phone number, email, and address in their respective sections in a table view, I think the easiest way would be to turn ContactInfo into three separate arrays: contactInfoPhoneList, contactInfoEmailList, contactInfoAddressList

I'm getting an error though if I don't initialize self.contactInfoPhoneList and the other two above the super.init, but I can't seem to call the contactInfoToList function before the super.init otherwise I get a can't call self in method call before super.init.

However, if I try to initialize them after the super init, then I an "Immutable value 'self.contactInfoPhoneList' may only be initialized once" error.

Is this how you would create three more arrays from an init, or should it be done differently? Any help solving the error would be greatly appreciated!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let contact: ContactStruct
    let contactInfo: [ContactInfo]
    let contactInfoPhoneList: [ContactInfo]
    let contactInfoEmailList: [ContactInfo]
    let contactInfoAddressList: [ContactInfo]


    init(contact: ContactStruct, contactInfo: [ContactInfo]) {

        self.contact = contact
        self.contactInfo = contactInfo

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        let contactInfoList = self.contactInfoToList(contactInfoList: contactInfo)

        self.contactInfoPhoneList = contactInfoList[0]
        self.contactInfoEmailList = contactInfoList[1]
        self.contactInfoAddressList = contactInfoList[2]


    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func contactInfoToList(contactInfoList: [ContactInfo]) -> [[ContactInfo]] {
        var phoneList = [ContactInfo]()
        var emailList = [ContactInfo]()
        var addressList = [ContactInfo]()

        for info in contactInfoList {
            switch info.contactInfoType {
            case .Phone:
                phoneList.append(info)
            case .Email:
                emailList.append(info)
            case .Address:
                addressList.append(info)
            }
        }
        return [phoneList, emailList, addressList]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

- Omit the extension and put the code in the `init` method

  ```
  init(contact: ContactStruct, contactInfo: [ContactInfo]) {

      self.contact = contact
      self.contactInfo = contactInfo

      var phoneList = [ContactInfo]()
      var emailList = [ContactInfo]()
      var addressList = [ContactInfo]()

      for info in contactInfo {
          switch info.contactInfoType {
          case .Phone:
              phoneList.append(info)
          case .Email:
              emailList.append(info)
          case .Address:
              addressList.append(info)
          }
      }
      self.contactInfoPhoneList = phoneList
      self.contactInfoEmailList = emailList
      self.contactInfoAddressList = addressList

      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  }
  ```
- Declare the constants the compiler is complaining about as `var` with an initializer

  ```
  var contactInfoPhoneList = [ContactInfo]()
  var contactInfoEmailList = [ContactInfo]()
  var contactInfoAddressList = [ContactInfo]()
  ```

Comment: Option 3 probably worth mentioning: move the function out of the class or make it a class function since it doesn't do anything involving the instance anyway.